# Botkit With Express

Tags: express, botkit, facebook-messenger-bot

The documentation at Botkit (https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/readme-facebook.md) is pretty not meaningful at all:

```
// if you are already using Express, you can use your own server instance...
// see "Use BotKit with an Express web server"
controller.setupWebserver(process.env.port,function(err,webserver) {
  controller.createWebhookEndpoints(controller.webserver, bot, function() {
      console.log('This bot is online!!!');
  });
});
```

Moreover, without a custom webserver (like express), Botkit doesnt provide a way to set the custom local url (instead, it simply chooses 0.0.0.0, which is impractical).

Is anyone successfully assembling `app = require('express')();` into the `setupWebserver` in Botkit (specially for Messenger). If yes, please present the full code.

Comment: If it's a unique https URL address you want for your application you can use https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 10):

Hostname for the built in express server can be set when creating your controller:

```
var controller = Botkit.facebookbot({
  hostname: 'YOUR_HOST_NAME',
  verify_token: '',
  access_token: ''
})
```

`controller.setupWebserver` and `controller.createWebhookEndpoints` are helper functions within botkit to do just what they describe, create an express webserver and webhook endpoints, respectively.

To implement your own webserver, you just need to setup a webhook endpoint for the botkit controller to receive message POST data at and perform auth handshakes.

By botkit convention this is `/{platform}/receive` so for facebook `/facebook/receive` but you can use whatever you like.

---

**To use a custom express server with Botkit, first create a basic webserver.**

```
// components/express_webserver.js

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var debug = require('debug')('botkit:webserver');

module.exports = function(controller, bot) {


    var webserver = express();
    webserver.use(bodyParser.json());
    webserver.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    webserver.use(express.static('public'));

    // You can pass in whatever hostname you want as the second argument
    // of the express listen function, it defaults to 0.0.0.0 aka localhost 
    webserver.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,  null, function() {

        console.log('Express webserver configured and listening at ',
            process.env.HOSTNAME || 'http://localhost/' + ':' + process.env.PORT || 3000);

    });

    // Register our routes, in this case we're just using one route
    // for all incoming requests from FB
    // We are passing in the webserver we created, and the botkit
    // controller into our routes file so we can extend both of them 
    require('./routes/incoming-webhook')(webserver, controller)

    controller.webserver = webserver;

    return webserver;

}
```

**Next you need to create the routes for webhook endpoints, we're doing this in a separate file as is common with express**

```
// components/routes/webhook.js 

module.exports = function(webserver, controller) {

    // Receive post data from fb, this will be the messages you receive 
    webserver.post('/facebook/receive', function(req, res) {

        // respond to FB that the webhook has been received.
        res.status(200);
        res.send('ok');

        var bot = controller.spawn({});

        // Now, pass the webhook into be processed
        controller.handleWebhookPayload(req, res, bot);


    });

    // Perform the FB webhook verification handshake with your verify token 
    webserver.get('/facebook/receive', function(req, res) {
        if (req.query['hub.mode'] == 'subscribe') {
            if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] == controller.config.verify_token) {
                res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
            } else {
                res.send('OK');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Once you have created these two files, you will use require and pass your controller into the express module. Your main bot file should look something like this**

```
// bot.js

var Botkit = require('botkit');

// Create the Botkit controller, which controls all instances of the bot.
var controller = Botkit.facebookbot({
    debug: true,
    verify_token: process.env.verify_token,
    access_token: process.env.page_token,
});

// Set up an Express-powered webserver to expose oauth and webhook endpoints
// We are passing the controller object into our express server module
// so we can extend it and process incoming message payloads 
var webserver = require(__dirname + '/components/express_webserver.js')(controller);
```

Comment: Saddly this solution breaks if we add `require_delivery = true` when creating controller. Without `require_delivery=true` it is almost imposible to create complex structure for conversation because bot.say(), bot.ask() are ignored. 
Here is a [link](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/883) to issue that I opened in github repository, mind checking that out?

Comment: @KārlisJanisels this issue has been fixed in a subsequent release, do not remember which but this should no longer be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find in github a, MIT-licensed, full [Demo of running BotKit for Facebook Messenger on an Express server with MongoDB storage](https://github.com/mvaragnat/botkit-messenger-express-demo).

Here is the main server.js

```
// modules =================================================
var express = require('express')     // framework d'appli
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser') // BodyParser pour POST
var http = require('http').Server(app)      // préparer le serveur web
var dotenv = require('dotenv')
var path = require('path')

// configuration ===========================================

// load environment variables,
// either from .env files (development),
// heroku environment in production, etc...
dotenv.load()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))

// parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing url encoded

// view engine ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// routes
require('./app/routes/routes')(app)

// port for Heroku
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

// START ===================================================
http.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('listening on port ' + app.get('port'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so here goes i was trying the same thing and have been able to start the botkit up with a custom url on express. You dont have to worry about this code at all:

```
controller.setupWebserver(process.env.port,function(err,webserver) {
controller.createWebhookEndpoints(controller.webserver, bot, function()     {
  console.log('This bot is online!!!');
 });
});
```

This repository has its own code with will work with a mongodb database and a express server.

```
git clone https://github.com/mvaragnat/botkit-messenger-express-demo.git

sudo npm install express --save
sudo npm link body-parser
sudo npm link dotenv
sudo npm install --save botkit
sudo npm install --save monkii
sudo npm install --save mongodb
sudo npm install --save request
sudo npm install --save ejs


In all of the above steps you can perform:
sudo npm link botkit
etc

Finally run node server.js
lt --subdomain botkit --port 5000
restart node server.js
```

Dont Forget to add your variables to .env file in the directory.

All your traffic on local host will be redirected to the localtunnel, you can get a url using the lt --subdomain name --port 5000

Use this generated url in the webhooks on your page and your bot should be online.